# Join four tables together when only two tables are connected to the junction table

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables created and I need join all the four tables and get the result. Following is the table structure. The `CAT` table is the junction table here and from it, it has one to many relations to `CATFOOD` and `CUBS` tables. From the `CATFOOD` table, there's another one to many relationship to the table `BRAND`.

[image]

I tried the following query to first join the `BRAND` and `CATFOOD` tables and next join the result of that with `CAT` table. But it didn't work. Please note that I also join the table `CUBS` with the table `CAT` too. Here's what I tried,

```
SELECT CAT.CAT_ID, 
           CAT_TYPE, 
           CAT_COLOR,CUBS.CUB_ID, 
           CUBS.CUB_NAME, 
           CATFOOD.CATFOOD_TYPE,
           CATFOOD.CATFOOD_ID,
           CATFOOD.CATFOOD_STATUS,
           CATFOOD.SELLER_ID,
           BRAND.BRAND_ID,
           BRAND.FLAVOUR
FROM CAT RIGHT JOIN CUBS
            ON CAT.CAT_ID = CUBS.CAT_ID
            RIGHT JOIN (
                SELECT CATFOOD.CATFOOD_ID,
                            CAT_ID,
                            CATFOOD_TYPE,
                            SELLER_ID,
                            CATFOOD_STATUS,
                       BRAND.BRAND_ID,
                            FLAVOUR
                FROM CATFOOD RIGHT JOIN BRAND
            ON CATFOOD.CATFOOD_ID = BRAND.CATFOOD_ID) 
            AS TEMP ON CAT.CAT_ID = TEMP.CAT_ID
WHERE CAT.CAT_ID = 'some_id_in_the_db';
```

When I execute this, I get the following error.

```
Unknown column 'CATFOOD.CATFOOD_TYPE' in 'field list'
```

When I remove the columns that the error message mention from the select statement, it doesn't give me any errors but returns an empty result.

What I simply want to achieve is get all the details related to a provided `CAT_ID` so in the java level, I can construct the response appropriately.

Please if anyone know how to achieve this, I appreciate it very much. Thanks in advance.

Update: previously, CATFOOD_TYPE field was mistakenly mentioned as CARFOOD_TYPE in the question. It is corrected now.

Comment: Because `CATFOOD_TYPE` is defined in the alias named `TEMP`, you should use `TEMP.CATFOOD_TYPE` in your field list.

Comment: Sorry, that should be CATFOOD_TYPE, not CARFOOD_TYPE. Updating the question now.

Comment: You should probably change the `RIGHT JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s...., Please also provide some sample data...

Comment: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: @AkilaAmarasinghe Can you provide some sample input output. It will be helpful to check.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining a subquery which contains the column `CATFOOD.CATFOOD_TYPE`, but this column is not visible to the outer query by that alias/name.
You should alias the subquery, say `t` and refer to the column as `t.CATFOOD_TYPE`.

But there is no need to complicate the requirement.
You can join the table `cat` with all the other tables with `LEFT` joins:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_type, c.cat_color,
       cu. cub_name,
       f.catfood_type, f.catfood_id, f.catfood_status,
       b.brand_id, b.flavour
FROM cat c
LEFT JOIN cubs cu ON cu.cat_id = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN catfood f ON f.cat_id = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN brand b ON b.catfood_id = f.catfood_id
WHERE c.cat_id = 'some_id_in_the_db';
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo, should be CATFOOD_TYPE, not CARFOOD_TYPE

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this =>

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CAT_ID, 
       CAT_TYPE, 
       CAT_COLOR,cb.CUB_ID, 
       cb.CUB_NAME, 
       cf.CATFOOD_TYPE,
       cf.CATFOOD_ID,
       cf.CATFOOD_STATUS,
       cf.SELLER_ID,
     bd.BRAND_ID,bd.FLAVOUR 
FROM CAT c
LEFT JOIN CUBS cb ON c.CAT_ID=cb.CAT_ID
LEFT JOIN CATFOOD cf ON c.CAT_ID=cf.CAT_ID 
LEFT JOIN BRAND bd ON cf.CATFOOD_ID=bd.CATFOOD_ID
```